# How to Manage Liquibase Database Rollbacks When Using Git Reset?

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, github-actions, liquibase

I am working on a project where we use Liquibase for database migrations, and our codebase is version-controlled with Git. Occasionally, I need to perform a git reset to undo some commits. However, I'm unsure about how to manage database rollbacks effectively in sync with Git resets.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on the following:

1. How can I automatically identify the appropriate Liquibase rollback point based on the Git history when I perform a git reset to a previous commit?
2. What are best practices for ensuring that my database schema is consistent with the state of the codebase after a Git reset?
3. Are there any tools or scripts that can help automate the rollback
   process in such scenarios?

I'd appreciate any insights, tips, or recommended practices for handling database migrations and rollbacks when working with Git resets in a development workflow.

Thank you for your assistance!